# JObject missing in .NET core, in NewtonSoft package

Tags: json, json.net, .net-core

I'm trying to load a json file in .NET Core. To do this I'm using the [`NewtonSoft` package](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). I successfully installed it, and

```
using NewtonSoft.Json;
```

produces no compiler errors. However when I try to load and parse a file as per their example, using

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("file.json"));
```

I get a compiler error, telling me that `JObject` does not exist. My suspicion is that there is a difference between .NET Framework and .NET Core implementation, but I don't know. In any case how do I load a json file using `NewtonSoft`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According [official docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), `JObject` class is in [`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) namespace, so you need another import:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("file.json"));
```

Comment: Your answer helped me in 2021. Thanks!